# Storing images using canvas2image function

Tags: html, canvas

I am using Canvas2Image() function to convert an canvas element to Image of jpg (or) png format. I want to know where will this image be stored and how can I access the converted image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read the documentation the user will be prompted to save the image as they wish. Additionally you cache make the function return a html img element if that's what you want.

But you can't save the image to the HDD and then modify it.

Comment: I want to store the Image into my Server side Database. Once the user draw using canvas and hit a Submit button , Canvas Element should be converted to image format and then I want to store that Image into my database for further use.

Comment: Add that detail next time please :) I'll probably just take the dataurl and save to the database. And send it to the server either by an ajax call or posting it with a form :) and then let the server handle the insert. If you want to save the image as a blob you could use the server to decode the dataUrl to the actual bytes and save that :)